# Expression binding with multiple conditions in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to set the `src` property of `sap.ui.core.Icon` based upon data being fetched from the data model. Something like this:

```
<Icon src="{= ${propertyname} === 'somevalue' ? 'sap-icon://arrow-top' : 'sap-icon://arrow-bottom'}"/>
```

I have one additional condition in my case which implies that:

- Set icon1 (say 'sap-icon://arrow-top') when property value is 'UP'
- Set icon2 (say 'sap-icon://arrow-bottom') when property value is 'DOWN'
- Set icon3 (say 'sap-icon://arrow-left') for **all** other cases

Is it possible to achieve this without the use of formatter function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply nest another ternary operator inside your expression.

```
<Icon src="{= ${propertyname} === 'UP' ? 'sap-icon://arrow-top' : ${propertyname} === 'DOWN' ? 'sap-icon://arrow-bottom' : 'sap-icon://arrow-left'}"/>
```

Comment: This is what OP wanted, but I'd prefer a clean formatter over a 150 chars long nested ternary operator anytime.